# How can I fix the backend connection issue for my React and Node chat system on my phone?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, localhost

I have a simple react and node chat system built, which uses web sockets. when I tried to access with computers ip adress from my phone it showed me front-end but for some reason backend was not working. I would be thankful to everyone who would answer me.

P.S both frontend and backend works fine in laptop where I run localhost from.

I tried connecting cors and turning off firewall as well as restarting everything mobile,computer, wifi router but didn't work

Comment: Did you mean access the PC from the iPhone? If you access `localhost` from your phone, localhost is *your phone*...

Comment: No I tried to acces localhost with computers ip adress and it is 100% correct bacause website's front-end is showng, but problem is backend not working

Comment: you also need to give ip address to your react code's API calls. Instead of localhost

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps within the frontend you are putting the url `localhost` to make api calls to the backend. Instead of localhost you may want to put the computer's public address.

In order to quickly test you may start a tunnel in your laptop and use that public URL to access. You can use something like https://pinggy.io or ngrok to do that.